# How to change .erlang.cookie location to outside user home directory?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am having trouble starting RabbitMQ since "rabbitmq" user doesn't have permissions in the user (ncoder) home directory (/usr/ncoder). I cannot provide local rabbitmq user write access to ncoder user's home directory as it is a network share.  How can I change the location of the cookie file to use `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` instead (where rabbitmq user has access) ?

Error:

> ncoder@serverA:/etc/rabbitmq$ sudo -u rabbitmq rabbitmqctl
>   start {error_logger,{{2016,3,19},{3,57,2}},"Error when reading
>   /usr/ncoder/.erlang.cookie: eacces",[]}
>   {error_logger,{{2016,3,19},{3,57,2}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{auth,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,

Answer (score 2):

First, `rabbitmqctl start` isn't a valid command. To start RabbitMQ, you need to use `rabbitmq-server`.

Now, about the location of the Erlang cookie file, it is imposed by Erlang. In your case, you should put `.erlang.cookie` in `/var/lib/rabbitmq`.

If Erlang is unable to find it there, verify the `$HOME` environment variable points to the actual home directory (so `/var/lib/rabbitmq`); sudo(1) should set it correctly.

Also, permission on `.erlang.cookie` must be set to 0400 or 0600: it must not be readable by the group or anyone.